# Secure git push and pull using git without password, from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, git-remote

I want to push and pull a repository from a remote server without having to use a password.  I have tried following using the Git guide, but it does not work, I still get asked for a password.

Here is what I've done:

1. Generate a key in `.ssh` on git

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C “git@github.com”
   ```

   New key is generated.
2. Copy and paste to remote server (Raspberry Pi) in `.ssh`.

But this does not work.  I cannot find anything on secure git push and pull from the remote server without password.

Comment: But the problem here is that remote server is Raspberry PI not GIT account. I have tried te other way where I can push and pull from the git to server. But I want my Git not to ask for password when push or pulling from root@192.168.0.24

Comment: There's no such thing as a "GIT account".  Set sshd up on your RP and follow the instructions.